# react-native: Switch Component onValueChange doesnt get called in Android

Tags: android, react-native

I've been struggling with a weird issue in switch components in React Native when running inside Android app.

Lets say, I have a component which render method looks like this:

```
render() {
return (
  <View>
    <View>
      <Text>
        Test Title
      </Text>
      <Switch
        value={ this.state.value }
        onValueChange={
          this.test.bind( this )
        }
      />
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

}

The `test` method is:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    value: true
  };
}


test(){
 this.setState( {value: !this.state.value})
}
```

When I run my module inside my iOS app the `onValueChange` method gets called and everything works as expected, however, when I do the same in my Android app the method never gets called when the value is changed to false. What is more, I cannot change the value more than once i.e I can only set the value to false and it will not allow me to set it to true afterwards. The only way I can play with the switch element again is by holding the bar, nonetheless, the value never gets changed (The switch component doesn't change its color) nor the method called .

Has anyone faced something similar? Is this a issue with RN and its Switch component for Android?

I am using:

- react: 15.4.1
- react-native: 0.39

***NOTE 1: The onValueChange gets called when I put my RN code inside an activity but it fails when it's inside a fragment.

Comment: Having a similar issue with the Android Picker RN component

Answer (score 4):

Try This.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: true
    };
 }
```

and in your render

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          Test Title
        </Text>
        <Switch
          value={ this.state.value }
          onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({value})}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

You can remove your `test()` function

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this way and it's still not working, actually the code above is a sample and my real render method has: `<Switch
            value={ item.value }
            onValueChange={
              ( value ) => {
                this.props.onChangeValue( this.props.index,
                  { ...item, value } )
              }
            }
            style = { this.props.style.switch_elem }
          />`. PS: I'm validating the props etc, as I said, it works for iOS. That's why I'm wondering whether it's a particular issue on RN or just me missing something.

Comment: it throws value not defined :(

Comment: @Danish can u past your full error and your code..?

Comment: @SantoshSharma i have wrote my solution that worked for me as a answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

what works for me is this,

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isOpen : false
        }
        this.onControlChange = this.onControlChange.bind(this); 
    }

onControlChange(value) {

    return this.setState({
        isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
 }
```

and in return use this way

```
render() {
    return (
        <Switch 
            onValueChange={this.onControlChange} 
            value={this.state.isOpen}
        />
    )
}
```

so i believe that you should declare binding for your function in constructor. I tested this for Android emulator only.

Hope this helps.